# Unique way to identify page instance within HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule, httpcontext

You can get the name of a page within HttpContext via Request.Path.

Is there a way to distinguish between different requests from the same page?

That is when two different instances of yourpage.aspx make a request, how can you distinguish between the two using HttpContext?

Comment: Why do you want to distinguish the requests? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Dino Esposito, in his ASP.NET book, uses httpmodules to distinguish between postbacks and refreshes to prevent multiple repeats of the same page processing, but the solution only works if one instance of a page is served.  If in the httpmodule using httpcontext, I can distinguish between the same pages, then I think I fix the problem.  I know other solutions exist and I might probably use those, but just seeing what's possible.

Comment: are you actually trying to identify requests from the same browser/user?

Comment: @matt-dot-net - It could be from any browser, any user, as long as it's a separate instance of the page.  BTW, I got an instance of currenthandler (re: your answer) if I used the PreRequestHandlerExecute event as opposed to the BeginRequest event.  I also tried your instance variable idea,  but the guid resets on every page refresh - I'm trying to keep it constant for the life of the page.

Comment: Steve, a page refresh is equivalent to a new request, and therefore a new page instance. The code I gave you will do exactly what you are asking, but I think maybe you are asking something different?  Perhaps you don't mean page "instance" but instead you just mean distinct application page.  Maybe you should use a private static Guid _pageID = Guid.NewGuid();  and that will give you what you want.

Comment: @matt-dot-net - You're right.  Your answer answers my question.  My question wasn't clear enough.  I should have worded the question something like: Is there a way to uniquely identify/mark each page requested no matter how many times the page is refreshed and to do so for the same page or different pages (that's a mouthful.) I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Or to reword my question another way, is there a way to mark/identify a page when it's initialized and no matter how many times it's refreshed or posted back, keep that mark/identifier the same.

Comment: Yes there is... use a static member variable.  something like Public static Guid PageIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();  You'll have to cast your HttpContext.CurrentHandler to your base page class, but then you can identify the unique page.

Comment: @matt-dot-net - This is a tricky question, I think I reworded it wrong again, my bad.  So for the static member variable.  If I browse to page.aspx and refresh/postback, that guid will always remain the same.  I agree.  But lets say I go to another browser or a new tab and open that same page, page.aspx again.  It has the same guid.  I'd like the second page that opened to have a different guid.  So there's two pages, each with different guids.  I'm doing a bad job of explaining this.  Take the database metaphor.  I'm looking for a primary key for each page if such a beast exists.

Comment: except that your primary key is a composite of PageId, BrowserID

Comment: so make a composite key - store in Context.Items a Tuple<Guid,String> of the aformentioned static page id guid and the browser's Session.SessionID - so Tuple<PageID,Session.SessionID> and store in a Hashtable

Comment: if you aren't using 4.0 make a new object with Guid and String properties and store in a HashTable in Context.Items

Comment: @matt-dot-net - I tried sessionid.  When I have two instances of the same page, the sessionid is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably want to do this in a base Page class, but here's what i would do

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Guid _instanceID;

    public Guid InstanceID
    {
        get { return _instanceID; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Default()
    {
        this._instanceID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

then using the HttpContext somewhere else in your code...

```
        if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is Default)
        {
            ((Default)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler).InstanceID;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, at the point of processing where I'm accessing currenthandler, it's null, since it's before the page gets instantiated.

Comment: umm... then what is it you are trying to identify??? from your original question: "when two different instances of yourpage.aspx make a request, how can you distinguish between the two using HttpContext?"

Answer (score 2):

Nothing built into ASP.NET will allow you to differentiate different "page instances" or requests from them.

However, you can easily add a `Guid` to your view state to uniquely identify each page. This mechanism works fine when you are in the Page class itself. If you need to identify requests before you reach the page handler, you need to use a different mechanism (since view state is not yet restored).

The `Page.LoadComplete` event is a reasonable place to check if a `Guid` is associated with the page, and if not, create one.

Comment: adding a guid to the viewstate will only identify a unique browser not a unique page instance.  I think however, you may have the answer he's looking for - just not the question he asked.

Comment: The Guid idea is something I use very effectively to reconnect a page on postback with data still held on the server. One has to keep an eye on viewstate size but an additional GUID isn't too cumbersome

Answer (score 1):

If you're using authentication, would it work for you to distinguish which user submitted the page?

You could use `System.Web.Httpcontext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

Answer (score 1):

just throwing this out there:  NInject (and other DI containers) use a scoping mechanism based on the HttpContext.Current object itself, so depending on what you're trying to do, you could attempt to retrieve a state object from the DI container and go from there.